# Free Library of working Excel Macro code

Tags: excel, vba

I have learned a tremendous amount about programming in VBA (specifically for Excel) from this blog and would like to return the favor. Over the last couple of years I have built a library of code that I believe others would find very helpful. This code is primarily centered around the use of Excel Tables. It includes macros like `AddRows()`, `Sort()`, `Filter()`, `Clear()`, `Copy()`, `Delete()`, and functions like `getRowCount()`, `lookup()`, `valueExists()`. These are all organized into a couple of classes and I've also built a workbook that demonstrates how each of these are used. My question is: How can I make this available (for free) to anyone interested?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about publishing code rather than about coding.


Comment: Also, Stack Overflow is not a blog. </pedantic>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish your code to GitHub, BitBucket, CodePlex and other sites with a liberal license and promote it wisely so that people can download/use and fork/improve the code.